# How to print all the lines not containing a string along with adjacent lines?

Tags: text-processing

I'm trying to wrap my mind around this task. I want from the following output, to exclude all the lines that contain `Auto-installed: 1` and the 2 lines before. I was naively thinking that `grep -v -B2 string` will solve the problem... needless to say, only makes it worse.

This is the content:

```
Package: libopencore-amrwb0
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 1

Package: transfig
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 0

Package: xfig-libs
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 1

Package: xaw3dg
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 0
```

And this is how the results look:

```
Package: transfig
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 0

Package: xaw3dg
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 0
```

(note, empty lines are not showing, if it doesn't show empty lines is a plus but is not required, also results should include the Packages which Auto-Installed values is 0)

I know I can [match line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5200353/792066) but either end in not printing anything or printing everything but the lines breaks in between.

Any solution is acceptable, it doesn't have to be grep ([it even can be emacs](http://xkcd.com/378/)).

Comment: Your text says delete the two lines before, your sample output says the two lines before and any redundant surrounding blank lines.  Which?

Comment: @Braiam - see my updates, I show how to do this w/ grep using your logic.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how structured your data is but if it is just as you show, how about the following:

```
grep -B2 'Auto-Installed: [^1]'
```

That assumes that every stanza includes an `Auto-Installed` line, which might not be correct.

Here's an awk program which I think does exactly as you asked.

```
awk 'BEGIN{deleted=3}
     !deleted{printf "%s",l[NR%3]}
     deleted {--deleted}
     {l[NR%3]=/./?$0"\n":$0}
     /Auto-Installed: 1/{deleted=3}
     END{for(i=NR+deleted;i<NR+3;++i)printf "%s",l[i%3]}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this'll do ya

```
sed ':a
     $!N                          # slurp
     /Auto-Installed: 1/s/.*//    # kill all buffered on match
     $!{/\n.*\n/{P;D}}            # P/D any third line, D cycles w/o read
     $!ba                         # if no P/D, cycle w/o read anyway
    '
```

Comment: I tried, this works fine too, just keeps blank lines which can easily be cleaned up a variety of ways!

Comment: I'd do it with a second sed 'cause I'm lazy :-)

Comment: Me too, others would give us a hard time for using too many commands but it's easier to `grep -v "^$"` afterwards to get rid of them. 73% of scripting is doing what's easier/lazier.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of even trying to deal with excluding them, why not just select the opposite lines, which happen to be what you want anyway?

```
$ grep -B 2 "Auto-Installed: 0" data.txt 
Package: transfig
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 0
```

#### Excluding sections that have "Auto-Installed: 1"

If you'd like to use `grep` but using your logic to approach the problem where you exclude sections that contain "Auto-Installed: 1" I didn't come up with this approach using the [PCRE facility](http://www.pcre.org/) within GNU grep.

```
$ grep -B2 -P 'Auto-Installed: (?!1)' data.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ grep -B2 -P 'Auto-Installed: (?!1)' data.txt 
Package: transfig
Architecture: amd64
Auto-Installed: 0
```

The above makes use of [Perl's lookahead feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns), `(?!..)`. This allows us to do the match looking for lines that don't contain a value of 1, after `Auto-Installed:`.  We then tell `grep` to display 2 lines (`-B2`) before then "match".

Comment: That's a nice one.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use the double-clawed hammer :(. But as I didn't found a way to this through and was wondering if it was possible. ;)

Comment: @Braiam - yeah grep can't do the range and the `-v` switch.

Answer (score 2):

And here's the obligatory Perl way:

```
perl -000ne 'print unless /Auto-Installed: 1/' file
```

The magic is the `-000`, this turns on Perl's *paragraph mode* which makes it split the files into paragraphs. In other words, records are separated by two or more consecutive `\n` characters.

This will also print the blank line between entries, to get rid of that, you could run

```
perl -000ne 'print unless /Auto-Installed: 1/' file | grep .
```

Comment: awk way for this, `awk '!/Auto-Installed:1/' RS= file`

Answer (score 2):

What you have is in fact records separated by blank lines. Rather than coding up some brittle parsing that depends on the order and number of lines, use a tool like awk or perl to process records separated by blank lines (paragraph mode).

```
awk -F '' '! /^Auto-Installed: 1$/'
```

Comment: I'm expecting that the lines before `Auto-Installed: 0` appears (which is determinant). I'm trying to build a package/autoinstalled relationship (which is my final goal) where I'm interested in the entries where Auto Installed is 0.

Comment: @Braiam The lines before `Auto-Installed: 0` do appear. `-F` with an empty argument sets awk to paragraph mode (this is similar to the Perl code in [terdon's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101636)).